# Differences between array and pointer string declaration

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strtok

I am working on splitting strings.

When I run this code, I got an error ( `Bus error: 10` on MacOs or SegFault on Linux).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char *str = (char *)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
  str ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I change the str declaration by `char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";` it works well.

Can anyone tell me why? My brain is melting.

Comment: Why do you call `malloc` if you don't use its return value?

Comment: It was a simple example, the real thing requires a value to be returned.

Comment: Please omit redundant code from your examples. They're only confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`

> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

As your code, `str` holds the base address of a statically allocated string literal which is usually *read-only*.

In your code, change

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
str ="- This, a sample string.";
```

to

```
char *str = malloc(1000);
strcpy(str, "- This, a sample string.");
```

Also, first allocating memory to `str` using `malloc()` and then *assignning* the string literal to `str` will *overwrite* the previously allocated memory returned by `malloc()`, resulting in memory leak.

Next,

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
```

this works well, because here you're *initializing* a local `array` and it's containts are *modifiable*.

Note:

**<sup>Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.</sup>**